# DIV table-cell width 0 (Internet Explorer 11)

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-11

got a problem here that gives me a huge headache.

I've got a div table, containing rows and cells.
One cell (right side) contains an Ajax TabContainer.
Clicking on a tab fires an event that is supposed to COMPLETELY hide the left cell and set the width of the cell (containing the TabContainer) to 100% of displaying area.

This works perfectly on firefox, Opera, Chrome.

Am I missing something?

Here's the code:

ASPX/HTML: http://pastebin.com/fWXetcPV

JS/jQuery: http://pastebin.com/xeddGLhh

Pictures:

FF/Opera/Chrome: http://s16.postimg.org/80wjx560z/ff_op_chr.jpg

IE: http://s1.postimg.org/7kbx5flz1/image.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with other problems I finally got the idea how to solve the issue.

Instead of setting only table-cell width to 0 I had to change the display-type to none.
This removed that ugly space bar.